# Using grep, to search the files in the directories, how can I get the occurrence count of each word using a list.txt(or csv)?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, wc

In the list.txt I have:

```
Lucas
Viny
Froid
```

In current directory, I have a lot csv files containing names.

I need to know how many times each word of my list appears on these csv files.

I tried:

```
grep -riohf list.txt . | wc -lw
```

But it return only the counts. I need to know which word each count refers to.

### I just need something like that:

```
Lucas 353453
Viny 9234
Froid 934586
```

Comment: Are all csv files having same input format. Share sample of 1 or 2 csv files

Comment: I'd use an awk script instead of grep.

Comment: Yes, all the csv files have the same format.
But they are very huge, with a lot columns.

Comment: I have never used awk before. I will study about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` and `wc` within a loop, you can count each individual occurrence of a word rather than just the lines.

```
while read -r line; do
    count=$(grep -o "$line" *.csv | wc -l)
    echo "$line $count"
done < list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have these files:

```
$ cat list.txt
Lucas
Viny
Froid

$ cat 1.csv
Lucas,Viny,Bob
Froid

$ cat 2.csv
Lucas,Viny,Froid
Lucas,Froid
```

You can use the following `awk` to count the fields that match a list:

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR==NR{cnt[$1]; next}
{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in cnt) cnt[$i]++}
END{for (e in cnt) print e, cnt[e]}' list.txt {1..2}.csv
Viny 2
Lucas 3
Froid 3
```

*Yet another way* is to use a pipeline to count uniq fields:

```
cat {1..2}.csv | tr , "\n" | sort | uniq -c
   1 Bob
   3 Froid
   3 Lucas
   2 Viny
```

Then `grep` that:

```
cat {1..2}.csv | tr , "\n" | grep -Fxf list.txt | sort | uniq -c
   3 Froid
   3 Lucas
   2 Viny
```

Comment: These do **not** work with quoted csv. If you have that, use a csv parser such as ruby, python, or perl.